# Krull dimension of abelian group ring equals that of generating submonoid ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, abelian-groups, semigroups, monoid

A book I am reading considers the following setting. Let $A$ be an abelian group and let $Q\subset A$ be a finitely generated submonoid which generates $A$ as a group.

In one argument it is claimed that for a field $k$ the Krull dimension of $k[A]$ equals that of $k[Q]$ with no explanation other than that the embedding $k[Q]\subset k[A]$ is visibly a localization map. What would be a proof of this fact concise enough to be omitted altogether? (I am thus looking for a short proof but, of course, any reasonable proof would be appreciated.)

(I can see that $\dim k[A]\le\dim k[Q]$. I can also see that the Krull dimension of $k[A]$ equals the rank $n$ of the torsion free part of $A$. One could then, probably, show that $k[Q]$ is a module-finite extension of a ring of the form $k[\mathbb Z^l\oplus\mathbb N^{n-l}]$ which would lead to a proof. However, such an approach seems to get messy.)

Comment: I suppose both are finitely generated $k$-algebras, and have the same field of fractions.

Comment: @user26857 Wait a second. They are not necessarily torsion-free, so the rings are not necessarily integral domains. Wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: @user26857 So their "total fraction rings" certainly should be the same but does that tell us anything about their Krull dimensions?

Comment: Hm, I'm used with affine semigroup rings, and these are torsion-free. (It would have been nice to give us an exact reference.)

Comment: @user26857 Yes, absolutely, me too. But in this particular section $A$ is an arbitrary finitely generated abelian group. Exact reference: Miller, Sturmfels, "Combinatorial Commutative Algebra", proof of Proposition 7.5.